# Jira REST API Java - missing artifact

Tags: java, maven

I have a problem when I want to connect to my jira localhost using java. I created maven project, and added dependency of atlassian plugin in pom.xml file. Here that dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency> 
 <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId> 
 <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-javaconfig</artifactId>
 <version>0.3.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

So I'm getting this error: "Missing artifact com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-osgi-javaconfig:jar:0.3.1".

Comment: This artifact does not exist in central repository...

Comment: Is there a solution to add it?

Comment: You need to search from which repository the dependency is available and add to your settings.xml file ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.plugins/atlassian-plugins-osgi-javaconfig/0.3.1) you have to specify their repository, like this:

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>Atlassian</id>
     <name>Atlassian Public</name>
     <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public</url>
   </repository>
 </repositories>
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. that error is disappeared, but now I'm getting error modules of `import com.atlassian.jira...`. I just added `repositories` sent by you. And my maven's project not exist `gradle` to add this `compile group: 'com.atlassian.plugins', name: 'atlassian-plugins-osgi-javaconfig', version: '0.3.1'`. Is there any idea?

Comment: Have you run a maven update, to download atlassian jar? Do you find it in your local repository?

Comment: No haven't run a maven update. (So I'm new in java, and don't know how I can update projects, etc.) atlassian jar there is only `JAVA DEPENDECIES` at the bottom. is it about that? (I'm using VS code)

Comment: I think in Visual Studio Code you need a plugin for Maven and depend of it you could run mvn update from terminal or using the plugin itself (sorry I don't use VS Code ^^)

Comment: Where does it say this??

Answer (score 0):

I came here as I had the same issue. I've tried the solution provided by @WoAiNii but it failed with a cryptic message. Yet one part of his answer brought me to the correct solution:

```
<repository>
      <id>atlassian-public</id>
      <url>https://packages.atlassian.com/mvn/maven-external/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
       <releases>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
</repository>
```

This is provided here: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/atlassian-maven-repositories-2818705/

This unfortunately brought up another error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project Java2Jira: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:Java2Jira:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find jta:jta:jar:1.0.1 in https://packages.atlassian.com/mvn/maven-external/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of atlassian-public has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

This was discussed on the internal board by Atlassian and the solution seems to be just to add it externally by adding this to your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jta</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1b</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```